# Magento 2 - How to add logo and link to payment method in checkout?

Tags: magento2, checkout, uicomponent, knockoutjs, amazon-payment

I am using Amazon Pay. Currently it looks like this in the checkout:

[image: Current State]

I need to add a logo and a link pointing to the info page about amazon pay:

[image: Target State]

I solved it with a workaround by adding a javascript at the bottom of the page...
but this is not clean enough. How can I solve it the proper way? I was not able to find the template.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Go to root magento/vendor/amzn/amazon-pay-module/view/frontend/web/template/checkout-button.html

You can add  and clear cache

example from payment method

app/code/Rabbit/Linepay/view/frontend/web/template/payment/Linepay.html

[image]

And I call function in js

hople help you.

Comment: Does not work. This changes the button at the very top where it says "use your amazon account". Thats not what I want. I want to change the field in the payment method selection.